# Best way to transfer files between iPhone and Windows PC

Tags: iphone, windows, file-transfer

Is there a software in Windows that will make file transfer between an iPhone and PC easier? I have tried iMazing. It's kinda great, but the problem is that when I am transferring files from my Windows PC  to iPhone, (videos to be precise), it doesn't transfer all the files that I need. I suspect it's the format.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you elaborate on what kind of files you are looking to transfer?

Comment: Just photos and videos. Like jpeg, gif, png, mp4, and some files that are playable in vlc like mkv and such... I find it hard because im used to android. Like whenever im transferring files in android its much more easier than apple. I tried some apps like anytrans and such but it suck bcs the features are limited. And i guess there is a specific format that apple allows so i guess some of my files are not able to pass thru

Comment: Try a cross-platform cloud solution such as DropBox or Google Drive. Using a cable is so 20th century. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The software you should be looking for is iTunes, specifically iTunes for Windows. You can download iTunes for Windows via:

- direct download from Apple's website using [this link](https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/).
- Microsoft Store using [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/p/itunes/9pb2mz1zmb1s).

If you wish to transfer and playback unsupported videos files on your iPhone, install [VLC for Mobile](https://itunes.apple.com/app/vlc-for-mobile/id650377962) on your iPhone and use iTunes File Sharing feature to easily transfer video files to your iPhone.

For detailed instructions regarding file sharing, refer to the Apple Support Article:

- [Use iTunes to share files between your computer and your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201301).

Comment: Also note that VLC has a built-in uploader so that one can completely bypass iTunes if you like.

Comment: iTunes enables syncing, which doesn't sound as though it's what the OP needs.